# How to uses FIDO2 hmac-secret extension for offline authentication?

Tags: authentication, hmac, fido2, offline

How hmac-secret extension defined in the CTAP2 Specification is used to help implement offline authentication with an authenticator. Is there any other specification that says how to do this?
From the exploration around, it looks like Microsoft is using this for offline login - https://groups.google.com/u/4/a/fidoalliance.org/g/fido-dev/c/tosNJvfjMBM

Comment: Stackoverflow is your friend when it comes to implementation and code.

Comment: Formulate your question more precisely.